# View permissions

Tags: 2010, view

I've created a form using custom list. There are hidden columns that will not appear in the form but will only appear in another view, and also editable in that view via datasheet view - I named it admin view.

Is there a way to add security to admin view so that the general user will not be able to see and edit the hidden columns?

I've hidden the columns by allowing management of content types then editing the column in content type.

Comment: whats your site template type ? team site ?  publishing site?

Answer (score 1):

Permissions are set on the list level, not any lower to things like fields or views. As alternative or workaround: Add users to 'Target Audience' of your admin view.

Comment: Target audience may not always work, assume there may be some other web parts which has shown to all and this restricted web part may block the view of other web parts. we are facing similar issue in my SP 2013 DMS portal. i dont have custom content types.

Comment: As you want it for a list view. You have to add edit your 'AdminView' page and add target audience to that particular webpart . This will not block any other view.